# Why do I get different exit status for ps | grep in a script?

Tags: shell-script, process, ps, exit-status

I am running below script :

```
#!/bin/bash

ps ax  | grep -q [v]arnish
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo varnish is running...
        exit 0
else
        echo "Critical : varnish is not running "
        exit 2
fi
```

The output is like ::

```
[root@server ~]# sh -x check_varnish_pro.sh
+ ps ax
+ grep -q '[v]arnish'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo varnish is running...
varnish is running...
+ exit 0
```

When I run same in command line I am getting exit status as 1:

```
[root@server ~]# ps ax  | grep -q [v]arnish; echo $?
1
```

The case is like varnish is not installed in the server. This script works fine in a server where varnish is installed.

Why different exit status when run using script and command line? How to improve this script?

Comment: Use a real process supervision system, not this kind of hackery. Your operating system will almost certainly have a built-in way to ensure that your daemons you want to stay up are automatically restarted on failure, be it upstart, daemontools, systemd, launchd, or one of the many, many other alternatives. *All* of them will be more robust and capable than this kind of hand-rolled hackery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run a script named `check_varnish_pro.sh` the test

```
ps ax  | grep -q [v]arnish
```

is successful because there is a script named `check_`**varnish**`_pro` running.

Answer (score 16):

In general, it's a bad idea to try the simple approach with `ps` and `grep` to try to determine if a given process is running.

You would be much better off using `pgrep` for this:

```
if pgrep "varnish" >/dev/null; then
  echo "Varnish in running"
else
  echo "Varnish is not running"
fi
```

See the manual for `pgrep`. On some systems (probably not on Linux), you get a `-q` flag that corresponds to the same flag for `grep` which gets rid of the need to redirect to `/dev/null`.  There's also a `-f` flag that performs the match on the full command line rather than on only the process name. One may also limit the match to processes belonging to a specific user using `-u`.

Installing `pgrep` also gives you access to `pkill` which allows you to signal processes based on their names.

Also, **if this is a service daemon**, and if your Unix system has a way of querying it for information (e.g., whether it's up and running or not), then that is the *proper* way of checking on it.

On Linux, you have `systemctl` (`systemctl is-active --quiet varnish` will return 0 if it's running, 3 otherwise), on OpenBSD you have `rcctl`, etc.

---

Now to your script:

In your script, you parse the output from `ps ax`. This output will contain the name of the script itself, `check_varnish_pro.sh`, which obviously contains the string `varnish`. This gives you a false positive. You would have spotted this if you had run it without the `-q` flag for `grep` while testing.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps ax | grep '[v]arnish'
```

Running it:

```
$ ./check_varnish_pro.sh
31004 p1  SN+     0:00.04 /bin/bash ./check_varnish_pro.sh
```

Another issue is that although you try to "hide" the `grep` process from being detected by `grep` itself by using `[v]` in the pattern. That approach will fail if you happen to run the script or the command line in a directory that has a file or directory named `varnish` in it (in which case you will get a false positive, again).  This is because the pattern is unquoted and the shell will perform filename globbing with it.

See:

```
bash-4.4$ set -x
bash-4.4$ ps ax | grep [v]arnish
+ ps ax
+ grep '[v]arnish'
bash-4.4$ touch varnish
+ touch varnish
bash-4.4$ ps ax | grep [v]arnish
+ ps ax
+ grep varnish
91829 p2  SN+p    0:00.02 grep varnish
```

The presence of the file `varnish` will cause the shell to replace `[v]arnish` with the filename `varnish` and you get a hit on the pattern in the process table (the `grep` process).

Comment: because everything is a file "in linux land".

Comment: @z_- Not quite sure how it's connected, but this holds true even on non-Linux Unices.

Comment: Not only the grep process; script being named `check_varnish_pro.sh` is also a factor.

Comment: @TNW I didn't spot that at first, but you are right. I'll add that in.

Answer (score 4):

[@AlexP explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337351/3645) very succinctly what is actually happening, but @Kusalananda's idea of **using `pgrep`/`pkill` for a critical process is [strongly discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_kill_a_process_by_name.3F__I_need_to_get_the_PID_out_of_ps_aux_.7C_grep_....).** Better solutions include:

- Asking the *service* whether it's running. `systemctl status varnishd` should take care of that on a modern *nix installation.
- If by some unfortunate circumstance you don't have a service available you can simply change the startup script to report the problem as soon as the process exits:

  ```
  varnish || true
  some_command_to_send_an_alert_that_the_service_has_died
  ```
- Alternatively change the script that starts the service to *record the PID,* and then check the state periodically with `kill -0 "$pid"`.

Comment: I agree, I was just addressing the shell scripting aspects of the problem. Note that `systemctl` is almost only available on Linux though (AFAIK), and not on all modern Unix-like systems.

Comment: [The original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/337309/1) had the tag "linux"; I'm not sure why that was removed by @muru.

Comment: Thanks l0b0. I had two questions "Why" and "How to improve". @AlexP's answer solved my first question and your answer is better solution for the second question. But Kusalananda explains things related to this which I think will be helpful for people who have similar issues. So I am confused now which to accept as answer.

Comment: @prado [Whichever solution works for you is usually the accepted one.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/130301)